# Java toggle policy, FocusTraversalPolicy

Tags: java, toggle, policy

I have a question, does this chunk of code set the newPolicy to null when togglePolicy.isSelected() ?

```
if ("toggle".equals(e.getActionCommand())) {
        frame.setFocusTraversalPolicy(togglePolicy.isSelected() ?
                newPolicy : null);
    }
}
```

Comment: No, it doesn't set `newPolicy` to anything. It sets the frame's focus traversal policy to `newPolicy` if `togglePolicy` is selected, and to `null` if `togglePolicy` is not selected.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, it sets frame focusTraversalPolicy to `null` when `isSelected()` is `false` (when it is not selected). if `isSelected()` was `true` it would set the newPolicy as the traversal policy.

you may want to take a look at [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you stumbled upon the *ternary operator*. It works as follows:

```
<condition> ? <result if true> : <result if false>
```

In your case, you evaluate `togglePolicy.isSelected()` first. If the evaluation returns `true`, than you set the policy to `newPolicy`. Else the policy will be set to `null`.